# SQL datetime2 cannot hold datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime2

It seems like that a `datetime2`, in some cases, cannot hold the value of a `datetime` value. Is this expected?

Notice the last 2 columns. Or is it the conversion corrupts the data?

```
SELECT
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS (2021, 2, 28, 10, 11, 12, 267),
    CONVERT(datetime, DATETIMEFROMPARTS (2021, 2, 28, 10, 11, 12, 267)),
    CONVERT(datetime2, DATETIMEFROMPARTS (2021, 2, 28, 10, 11, 12, 267)),
    CAST(DATETIMEFROMPARTS (2021, 2, 28, 10, 11, 12, 267) AS datetime2)
```

[image]

I don't really need these conversions, but I am having problems with Entity Framework, that is generating SQL casting my `datetime` to `datetime2`, resulting in small differences when loading it into C# `DateTime`

Comment: What do you mean, it can't hold the value of a `datetime`? `datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second, `datetime2` can be accurate to 1/1000000 of a second. It can hold every value of a `datetime` and more.

Comment: Yes that is what I expected, but the SQL I provided tells a different story.

Comment: No it doesn't, @Stig.

Comment: Shorter answer - read the documentation.

Comment: @SMor I have read it. But if datetime is using a precision base on an infinite decimal fraction (1/300), how should datetime2 represent this? (with the same precision)

Answer (score 4):

Your misunderstanding is that you think that a `datetime` is accurate to 1/1000 of a second; it is **not**. `.267` is not `.267000` in a `datetime`, it's `.266666~`, because `datetime` is accurate to 1/300 of a second.

When, therefore, you convert a `datetime` to a `datetime2` with an precision of 4 or more then that 1/300th of a second will be represented correctly. Thus `267` for a `datetime` = `.2666667` in a `datetime2(7)`.

If you want `267` then use a `datetime2(3)` not a `datetime2(7)`.

*Note on 2014 (and prior) SQL Server used to incorrectly convert `.267` to `267000` for the newer date and type data types. This was changed in SQL Server 2016. See [Breaking Changes in SQL Server 2016 (13.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#SQL15).*

Comment: Okay thanks, so when casting datetime to datetime2 (without being precision specific) may give you another value. Actually this is a little odd, since MS datetime specification says Accuracy is "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds". If this was the case it should fit perfect in a datetime2.

Comment: *"may give you another value"* No, it gives you the precise value, not another value. the `datetime` value `2021-01-01T10:00:00.267` and the `datetime2(7)` value `2021-01-01T10:00:00.2666667` are the **same** exact value, as both data types are representing 2/300ths of a second as accurately as they can, @Stig .

Comment: If datetime is accurate to 1/300 (infinite fraction), wouldn't it then be more precis in these cases, compared to datetime2?

Comment: 1/300 != 0.003000 @Stig .... 1/300 = 0.003333333~ Just like 2/600

Comment: I would disagree, it is not the same value. Also when loaded to .Net DateTime, these are not equal.

Comment: They **ARE** equal, @Stig ... That is not up for debate, it's basic maths. Again `1/300` = `0.0033333~` not `0.0030000` (the latter is `3/1000`).

Comment: Exactly that is my point. datetime represents 2.66666666666666 (etc.) and datetime only represents 2.666667. It is like comparing Decimals and doubles/floats

Comment: It seems I can't convince you that `1/300` != `3/1000` here, @Stig . I've explained, if you don't like the reason because that's how maths, and accuracy works, then I can't help you here; your understanding is simply flawed. I can assure you, if I have the value `1/3` and expanded the accuracy from 1 decimal point to 7 I would not expect `0.3000000` as it's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229314/discussion-between-stig-and-larnu).

Comment: I have nothing further to discuss here, @Stig . I've stated the reason; how numbers work isn't going to change.

Comment: If you're really still not convinced, read, the document I linked to: *"Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from datetime to datetime2 data types show improved accuracy by accounting for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted values. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists. For more information, see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261)."*

Comment: You are a little fast with your verdicts, I totally agree that 1/300 != 3/1000, never said it wasn't. But when datetime datatype has a fraction based storage type, it can represent values that the that datetime2 cannot. 1/3 is not the same as .3333333.

Comment: I should have written "But when datetime datatype storage type based on an infinite decimal fraction, it can represent values that the that datetime2 cannot"

Answer (score 2):

`DATETIMEFROMPARTS` returns a `datetime`, which is only accurate to 1/300 second. when you CAST a `datetime` to `datetime2(7)`, the fraction portion is extended to the precision of 7.

Use `DATETIME2FROMPARTS` with the desired precision specification:

```
SELECT convert(datetime2, DATETIME2FROMPARTS (2021,2,28,10,11,12,267,3));
SELECT convert(datetime2, DATETIME2FROMPARTS (2021,2,28,10,11,12,2670000,7));
```

`CONVERT` is unnecessary here unless you want to change the precision of the result.